# How to resolve ModuleNotFoundError?

Tags: python, package, python-import, python-module

I want to import *abc.py* in *main.py* and *abc.py* itself imports *xyz.py* and *pqr.py*.
Following is my project structure:

```
main_folder
    |
    +--main.py
    |
    +--inside_folder
        |
        +--sub_folder
            |
            +--abc.py
            |
            +--xyz.py
            |
            +--subsub_folder
                |
                +--pqr.py
```

For doing so:
I have written the following lines in  *main.py*:
`from inside_folder.sub_folder import abc`
And abc.py contains

```
from inside_folder.sub_folder.subsub_folder import pqr 
from inside_folder.sub_Folder import xyz
```

I also tried importing without the inside_folder.sub_folder part from the *abc.py* file, however doing so it reports `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Please help me resolve this problem.

Note:
I have added ***init**.py* to all the folders. Still the error cannot be resolved.

Comment: You missed to add `__init__.py` files for your [packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: @KlausD. I forgot to mention, but all the folders have ```__init__.py```  file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using python2 you won't find any problem with the above folder structure if every folder has `__init__.py` file with below code
**main.py**

```py
from inside_folder.sub_folder import abc
```

**abc.py**

```py
from subsub_folder import pqr 
import xyz
```

but if you are using python 3 you need to change your `abc.py` to

```py
from .subsub_folder import pqr 
from . import xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

- your packages (folders acting as a single python namespace) should probably have a `__init__.py` file to declare them as packages, though IIRC [it's not quite necessary anymore in some cases](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) it's easier to just do it
- `from inside_folder.sub_folder import abc` is completely wrong, following PEP 328 this tells Python to look for a top-level `inside_folder`. You need to use a *relative import* here so Python looks for a *sibling* to the importing file aka `from .inside_folder.sub_folder`
- though that assume you're completely outside the tree you're showing us and doing `from main_folder import main.py` or running `python -mmain_package.main`, the `PYTHONPATH` will be set up differently otherwise
- the structure you show does not match your import, `abc.py` is *next to* `sub_folder`, not inside it

Comment: Actually all the files and folders below the sub_folder are inside the sub_folder. I am poor at markdown editing skills. Some one edited it incorrectly.